# I need help writting a program for our nonprofit

Tags: python

I volunteer for a non-profit animal rescue/shelter. I wanted to make a program where we can put the name and age of an animal and it schedules the upcoming vaccines and wormers. The problem with this is 1) Depending on the age and what the animal is getting there are different dates they would get things we are doing this all on paper at the moment and animals are missing critical vaccines that keep them safe 2) I have no idea what I am doing.

I have tried YouTube, Google, and different sites but nothing seems to do exactly what I need. Update- I also just reached out to one of the "Professional" sites and said this was too complicated for them. I am at a loss right now.

Comment: what are the exact conditions for scheduling vaccination?

Comment: We have 2 different vaccines 1 is the DHPP shot and the other is Bordetella. Dogs under 6 months who come into the shelter need 1 inital work up with the 2 vaccines, 3 days of wormer, flea and tick meds, and heartgard meds. 2 weeks later they need their 2nd dhpp shot and 2 weeks after that they need their 3rd dhpp shot, monthly flea and tick and heartgard. Dogs 6 months to a year only need the initial work up and then 2 weeks later their 2nd dhpp as well as monthly flea and tick and heartgard.

Comment: dogs one year and up need the inital work up, monthly flea and tick all dogs YEARLY get a dhpp and bordetella as well as monthly flea and tick and heartgard depending on how bad worms are we either give wormer for 3,5,10 days. We usually use panacur or strongid which is 1cc per 5lbs these are for either 3 or 5 days Albon is for coccidia and it is for 10 days

Comment: The puppies are usually adopted out or rescued before the yearly appointments come into play so if there was a way to flag them as adopted or something like that when an appt comes up that would be amazing. or no longer needed

Comment: SO isn't the place to get someone to write an entire app for you.  This is something that'd be well within reach of an undergrad (or possibly high school) CS student -- maybe try some networking?

Comment: One sort of off topic observation: this should be very easily doable on paper with a combination of a calendar (to track the upcoming important dates for all patients) and an alphabetized file (to track individual patient status).  This is also roughly the way the data would be organized in an app, but unless you have many thousands of animals, there's no reason you *need* a database to manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic structure of the program that should do most of the work that you intend to do. Might not be perfect as your requirements are not 100% clear, but you can make necessary changes to meet your requirements.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, age_in_months):
        self.name = name
        self.age_in_months = age_in_months
        self.vaccination_schedule = []
        self.wormer_schedule = []
        self.adopted = False

    def schedule_vaccinations(self):
        if self.age_in_months < 6:
            self.vaccination_schedule.append(('Initial DHPP and Bordetella', 0))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('3 days of wormer', 0))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Flea and tick meds', 0))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Heartgard meds', 0))
            self.vaccination_schedule.append(('2nd DHPP shot', 14))
            self.vaccination_schedule.append(('3rd DHPP shot', 28))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Monthly flea and tick', 0))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Monthly Heartgard', 0))
        elif 6 <= self.age_in_months < 12:
            self.vaccination_schedule.append(('Initial DHPP and Bordetella', 0))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Flea and tick meds', 0))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Heartgard meds', 0))
            self.vaccination_schedule.append(('2nd DHPP shot', 14))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Monthly flea and tick', 0))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Monthly Heartgard', 0))
        else:
            self.vaccination_schedule.append(('Initial DHPP and Bordetella', 0))
            self.vaccination_schedule.append(('Yearly DHPP and Bordetella', 365))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Yearly Wormer', 365))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Monthly flea and tick', 0))
            self.wormer_schedule.append(('Monthly Heartgard', 0))

    def mark_as_adopted(self):
        self.adopted = True

    def print_schedule(self):
        print(f"Schedule for {self.name}:")
        print("Vaccination Schedule:")
        for task, days in self.vaccination_schedule:
            print(f"- {task} in {days} days")
        print("Wormer Schedule:")
        for task, days in self.wormer_schedule:
            print(f"- {task} in {days} days")
        print("Adopted: ", self.adopted)


def main():
    animals = []

    while True:
        print("Animal Information:")
        name = input("Enter the name of the animal (or 'view' to view the animal schedule): ")
        if name == 'view':
            if not animals:
                print("There are no animal records to view. Please enter a record first.")
            else:
                break
        else:
            age_in_months = int(input("Enter the age of the animal in months: "))
            animal = Animal(name, age_in_months)
            animal.schedule_vaccinations()
            animals.append(animal)

    while True:
        print("\nSelect an option:")
        print("1. Print Schedules")
        print("2. Mark an Animal as Adopted")
        print("3. Exit")
        option = input("Enter your choice: ")

        if option == '1':
            for animal in animals:
                animal.print_schedule()
        elif option == '2':
            name = input("Enter the name of the adopted animal: ")
            for animal in animals:
                if animal.name == name:
                    animal.mark_as_adopted()
                    print(f"{name} has been marked as adopted.")
                    break
            else:
                print(f"No animal with the name '{name}' found.")
        elif option == '3':
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid option. Please try again.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```